# Using entered value in another function

Tags: c, function

This is my problem:
I need to enter a value X (a number) in the main function and then use this scanned value in other function. This is a short part of my code but I think it's enough to understand what I mean here. 
I think it's solvable by using something like this `int main(int argc, char *argv[], int Z)` and the same thing in void function or using pointers but it didn't work for me when I tried. Maybe someone can explain and show how to do it properly?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int Z;
.... // rest of the code
    printf("Enter Z value:");
    Z = scanf("%d", &Z);
}
void function1(float array[100]){
    int i, Z, A=0;
    for(i=0; i<100;i++){
        if(array[i]>Z){
        A++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of thing missing in your code.

Comment: @dazzle  There is a call of function1?

Comment: It's just a small part of my code. And I only need to know how can I get the same Z value which I entered in the main function to be available in the second function.

Comment: `Z = scanf("%d", &Z);` ??? `scanf("%d", &Z);` !!! If you affect `Z` to the return of `scanf()`, you will erase the value...

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, everything works in my code. Just Z value is always 0 in second func.

Comment: Please pick a good beginner level book to start with `C`. For instance `Z = scanf("%d", &Z);` might not be what you want. Also, look for global variables.

Comment: @dazzle You can just declare one more parameter in function1 that will accept the value of Z.

Comment: Clearly the most appropriate is you take some book on C programming. But for now, read carefully the reference for the scanf function (try cplusplus.org for example), and you need to understand the concept of scope of a variable (int Z is not the same in main() and in funciotn1(), different functions are different scopes.)

Comment: @douglasjfm I completely understand that Z is 2 different things in each function and I was looking for the way to make it the same. Kinda found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the `scanf` in wrong way. You are overwriting the value read to with `scanf` with the value returned by `scanf`.

```
int Z;
...
if( scanf("%d",&Z) == 1) 
// Z is inputted correctly
```

Now you want to pass it , there are different ways to do that.

Is there any chance that you may change the value of `Z` in other function to which you passed it as argument and want to retain the changed value in the callee function?

If yes, then you pass the address of it using pointer and then derefrence it to access the original variable.

```
someFun( &Z );
```

Then in `someFun()`

```
void someFun( int * pZ){
   //read it
   printf("%d", *pZ);
   // write over it
   if( scanf("%d",pz) == 1){ /**/ }
   *pZ = 2017;
}
```

If answer was no, then you can simply pass the copy of the variable.

```
someFun1(Z);

void someFun1(int ZZ){
  // read it 
  printf("%d", *pZ);
  //write it
  Z = 2017;
  //But this change won't be reflected on the `main()` or callee function 
}
```

One thing that might bother you at first is both `pZ` and `ZZ` are local variable in the functions `someFun()` and `someFun1()` respectively. But their content is different.

In the first case, `pZ` is a local variable containing the address of the variable `Z` and `ZZ` is also a local variable containing the same value as `Z`. Then you may ask, why is there a difference?

Because in first case by going to the address (de-referrencing it) you are making change to the actual variable local to the `main()` whose address you passed.

In second case you are not getting the address, you are making chnages to the local variable of `someFun1` and that chnage is happening in a completely different place than the original variable's. That's why it isn't reflected in `main()`.

Quoting the standard the `scanf` returns

> **`§7.21.6.4`**
>
> The `scanf` function returns the value of the macro `EOF` if an input
>   failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
>   Otherwise, the `scanf` function returns **the number of input items
>   assigned**<sup>$</sup>, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the
>   event of an early matching failure.

<sup>$: input items successfully matched and assigned</sup>

Comment: Fixed it myself with this method right before I saw your code but thanks anyway!